# What is the format of the .matches() method on Scala strings?

Tags: regex, string, scala

I am well-aware that there is a very well-documented regex API in Scala that I should use for any real application. However I remain curious about the `.matches()` method that exists on `String` objects. Using the regex API, this trivial example works just fine:

```scala
".".r.findFirstIn("abc")
```

I get the following output in `amm`:

```scala
Option[String] = Some("a")
```

This does not work however; it evaluates to `false`:

```scala
"abc".matches(".")
```

This evaluates to `true`:

```scala
"abc".matches(".+")
```

I've been digging and digging and I can't seem to find an exact specification of this non-standard regex format. Does it exist and, if so, where?

Comment: A quick Google Search for "Scala Regex Reference" yields [Scala Standard Library 2.13.2 - scala.util.matching.Regex](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) as the second search result, which says "See [the documentation for java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for details about the regular expression syntax for pattern strings."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matches` performs "full match" so the whole provided string should match the regex. In case of one line string corresponding `findFirstIn` would look something like:

```
"^.$".r.findFirstIn("abc") // results in None
```

And for `"."` match would be any string with one character:

```
"a".matches(".") // true
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with *"non-standard"* regex format?

Checking the [**Javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) it says:

> An invocation of this method of the form str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the expression

```scala
Pattern.matches(regex, str)
```

Which follows the specifications of any other regex.

Also, the regex `.` doesn't match the string `abc`.

Comment: So basically it's a bit similar to re.search vs. re.match in Python

Comment: This was more or less illuminating but check out the other answer!